# Select в условии if на pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Пишу скрипт на PL/SQL с условием:

```
if ((select *
     from table1 
     where quant>1000) is not null) 
then ... 
else RAISE error$e; 
end if;
```

При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

Можно ли подставить запрос прямо в условие, а не создавать новую переменную?

Comment: А с каких пор SELECT выдает boolean-значение, чтобы использовать его в if-else?

Comment: ``is not null`` выдаёт булево значение, если что

Comment: В этом случае запрос должен возвращать один столбец и одну строку, т.е. одно оцениваемое значение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо, подразумевается

```
if exists (select *
         from table1 
         where quant>1000)
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что такое есть? Может в sql и where вместо if?
exec if exists (select 1 from dual) then null; end if;
PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only

Comment: Не уверен.
Но в IF должно быть логическое условие - я его и предложил.

Comment: А, так это тогда псевдо код, exists в plsql отделно  нет, только как метод в коллекции.

Comment: Я не помню, как выглядел этот вопрос в 2011 году, когда я на него отвечал. Вполне возможно, что тег Oracle тогда не был указан.

Answer (score 8):

Нельзя. Выражение `select ...` это указатель на курсор, `IF` ожидает логическое выражение.

Запрос лучше обернуть в функцию. Сделайте так:

```
create table table1 (quant number);
insert into table1 values (0); 

declare
    function existsHighQuant return boolean is
    begin
        for r in (select 1 from table1 where quant>1000) loop return true; end loop; return false;
    end;
    -- или так - не очень изящный по моему мнению вариант 
    function existsRow(stmt varchar2) return boolean is
       curs sys_refcursor;
       dummy number;
    begin 
        open curs for stmt; fetch curs into dummy; return curs%found;
    end;
begin 
    if existsHighQuant then 
        null; --do something
    else 
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'quant gt 1000 not found'); 
    end if;
    
    if existsRow('select 1 from table1') then dbms_output.put_line('at least 1 row exists'); end if;
end;
/

ORA-20000: quant gt 1000 not found

insert into table1 values (2000); 
-- повторить вызов блока

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
at least 1 row exists
```